# JavaScript to select radio button which are in a loop

Tags: javascript, php

I want to select or deselect all the radio buttons using one button. This JavaScript code is working fine if the radio button name is like 'radio1'. But I have to use use loop where radio button name is like 'radio[$i]'. How can I make the JavaScript work for this type of radio button?

```
function selectAll( prefix, set ) {
    var form = document.forms[0], //Get the appropriate form
        i = 0,
        radio;
    while( radio = form[prefix + ++i] ) //Loop through all named radio# elements
        for( var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++ ) //Loop through each set of named radio buttons
            if( radio[j].value == (set ? "yes" : "no") ) //Selector based on value of set
                radio[j].checked = true; //Check that radio button!
}





while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo"<tr><td>{$row['roll']}</td>
            </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='radio[$i]' value='Yes'>YES</td>
                  </td><td></td><td></td><td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio[$i]' value='No'>NO</td></tr>";
                  $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

better not take names of radio button as array, do it by concating your $i with name.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo"<tr><td>{$row['roll']}</td>
            </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='radio'.$i ?>' value='Yes'>YES</td>
                  </td><td></td><td></td><td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio'.$i ?>' value='No'>NO</td></tr>";
                  $i++;
        }
```

Comment: Just take the radio buttons inside a form and post it.